# How do you set a cursor's position in a different window/application?

Tags: c#, winforms, position, window, cursor

I'm trying to set a cursor position to a specific set of coords in a different window, but the mouse never refreshes on that window unless I move the physical mouse I have.

This is for a program that moves the users cursor for them to a specific location IN A DIFFERENT WINDOW, and clicks after a logical expression returns true.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

I want the cursor to actually move inside of a window and not just in form1.
The code will move the cursor to that position but it will not move on the window I am currently on.

Comment: Moving the cursor is almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: Do you not need to set the input focus on the required window first ?

Comment: The problem is that it's just hidden or does not appear to be on the window. Only moving my mouse by a pixel or more will show its new position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending RAW Input data to use mouse. Some applications read raw mouse strokes while others read virtual mouse strokes.

````
int to_x = 500;
int to_y = 300;
int screenWidth = InternalGetSystemMetrics(0);
screenHeight = InternalGetSystemMetrics(1);
// Mickey X coordinate
int mic_x = (int)System.Math.Round(to_x * 65536.0 / screenWidth);
// Mickey Y coordinate
int mic_y = (int)System.Math.Round(to_y * 65536.0 / screenHeight);
// 0x0001 | 0x8000: Move + Absolute position
Mouse_Event(0x0001 | 0x8000, mic_x, mic_y, 0, 0);
// 0x0002: Left button down
Mouse_Event(0x0002, mic_x, mic_y, 0, 0);
// 0x0004: Left button up
Mouse_Event(0x0004, mic_x, mic_y, 0, 0);```
````

Comment: Thanks. Typo screenHeight (forgot the int). Complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18379218/10789707

Answer (score 0):

```
Point cursorPos = Cursor.Position;
  cursorPos.X = control.PointToScreen(coordinate).X;
  Cursor.Position = cursorPos;
```

Comment: It gives me two errors, first control is undefined, then cannot convert int to system.drawing,point.

Comment: Please try to elaborate your answer more and explain what you are doing. Code-Only answered are considered as low-quality answers.